# Reducing carpet dust without removing the carpet

Tags: cleaning, dust, carpet

I have a room with a carpet, and it's dusty. Rooms without carpet get less dusty, and dust allergy advise is always to get rid of carpets.

Unfortunately I have other health issues that make it difficult to remove the carpet, so other than paying someone to move all my stuff and lay a nice hard floor, what options are there for reducing the impact on dust and my health?

I already have a Dyson vacuum and it never fails to remove a lot of dust, much of it very fine like talcum powder.

Comment: "Reducing carpet dust without removing it", the syntax of this sentence makes it sound like OP wants to reduce the dust without fully removing the dust, this was my initial interpretation. This title resambles "the three men stood at the corner smoking pipes", and "at the racetrack I saw a horse that was oval-shaped and 500 meters long".

Comment: You realise that unless the carpet itself is *actually producing the dust* [highly unlikely unless it's decades old] then the rooms without carpet just have the same amount of dust, not trapped, but free to roam.

Comment: Well, it is about 20 years old.

Comment: When is the last time you replaced or cleaned your HVAC filter?

Comment: I don't have a HVAC filter. There is central heating with a boiler, that's it. I have an air purifier in the room with filters changed six months ago.

Answer (score 4):

If the carpet isn't really soft and squishy you can lay hard flooring over it with some underlayment. Otherwise, vacuum and vacuum often. Roomba perhaps?

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. I will give it some thought, perhaps there is an easy to way to do the whole room in stages that I can manage even with my health issues.

Answer (score 3):

I have had good luck with professional services for cleaning carpets. The processes and tools they use are far strong than the mighty Dyson (which I also use). Having them come every year or so dramatically helped with my allergies as a kid. They may even be able to help with other furniture which aggravate allergic reactions.

Comment: That's a great idea. I will have a look to see what is available around here.